# How can i check EOF while deserializing in java using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, deserialization, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

I am trying to deserialze some file in java using ObjectInputStream. I am able to read all the objects successfully but getting the EOFException. Couldn't able to find the way to check for EOFException.
Tried below code.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

*Thanks for the help*

```
    List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destionation>();
    try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
      Destination destination = null;
            while(true) {
                destination = (Destination) in.readObject();
                if(destination == null)
                    break;

                destinationList.add(destination);
            }

            // Some code here

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note :- ** I only have the serialzed file.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace and provide code for serialization also

Answer (score 0):

The `EOFException` means that your `ObjectInputStream` has reached the file end while reading through a serialized object, this means a corrupted file in most cases, or you are still reading after your `ObjectInputStream` has reached `eof`, which seems to be your case considering the way you wrote your code, any way you can check for it by declaring it in the `catch` clause:

```java
    List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destionation>();
    try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
      Destination destination = null;
            while(true) {
                destination = (Destination) in.readObject();
                if(destination == null)
                    break;

                destinationList.add(destination);
            }

            // Some code here

    } catch (EOFEception eofEx){
        eofEx.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I don't think this is what you're looking for, what you need is a way to read objects without this problem, you can do this:

```java
    List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destionation>();
    try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
      Destination destination = null;
            while(true) {
               try{
                   destination = (Destination) in.readObject();
                   destinationList.add(destination);
               }catch (EOFEception eofEx){
                   break;
               }
            }

            // Some code here

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

by any means, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectInputStream.readObject` does not return `null` for end of input.

For a `null` terminated list of objects, you can write a `null` at the end of the file with `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject`.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
But O am not the one who  created this seriralize file.
Though I will try your solution for while creating any other serialize file.